# Cat multiple sources to multiple targets

Tags: bash, csv, cat

I have several servers that log some data into .csv files and send the files to a NAS. I need to add each .csv file to a corresponding aggregate logfile. Googling has turned up nothing relevant (perhaps I'm not using the right searchstring?)

The way I'm doing this now is by having a script like so:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

cat a.log a.csv > a.log
cat b.log b.csv > b.log
cat c.log c.csv > c.log
:
```

If new logging data is created then I need to edit the script and add a new line.

Surely, it must be possible to do this more easily and flexible. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: you're wiping out your existing X.log file with the `> a.log`. Why not just `cat a.csv >> a.log`? Read about `>>` (i.e. append redirection). Better be working with some replaceable test files until you get this working ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Yes the `>>` does seem smarter. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you dumping the contents of a.log into a.log?  This seems to make no sense.

I think you actually want to do this:

```
for logfile in *.log; do
    csvfile=${logfile/.log/.csv}
    cat $csvfile >> $logfile
done
```

which, I believe, is the equivalent of this:

```
cat a.csv >> a.log
cat b.csv >> b.log
cat c.csv >> c.log
```

Caveat: I don't have a

Comment: I think you're right adding the new data by using `>>` does seem smarter. Could you explain the second line in your proposed solution? I don't understand what it does. Is it some kind of `sed` shorthand?

Comment: there are 3 "regions".  1: the value in the logfile variable.  2.  change one occurrence of this string.  3. into this string.

Basically: in the value (in the logfile variable) change .log into .csv

Comment: For more details, search for "${parameter/pattern/string}" on this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know bash could do that :-D  You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that all log files have an equivalent csv file

```
for i in $(ls *.log); do
    logfile=$i
    csvfile=${i/.log/.csv}
    cat $logfile $csvfile > $logfile
done
```

it basically asks for a list of log file in the directory.

then, it 'computes' for the csv file name

then it runs your command, but this time automatically for each log file in your directory.

Comment: Nice, although the `ls` is spurios. How about `for i in *.log ; do`?

Comment: just learned about bash scripting a few days ago. :P thanks for the comment. i now know better.☺